# Match input field with CNIC Number in PHP?

Tags: php, html, regex, forms

I want to match the mentioned regular expression with the CNIC number input field but I can't figure out how? Here are my regular expression and code. Any help would be highly appreciated.

1. If the user matched something and it matches the pattern then it will display "valid" in the below span.
2. If it is not matched then it will display "invalid".

My desired result pattern is 12345-1234567-1

```html
<?php

    // NIC Validation
    // valid ouput sample 12345-1234567-1
   $nicRegex = '^([0-9]{5})[-]([0-9]{7})[-]([0-9]{1})$';


  if (empty($_GET["nic"])) {
            $nicError = "Please enter the nic number";
          }
  // if nic does match it should display valid else invalid       

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form Validation Example</title>
    <style>
        span{
            color:red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

 
  <hr width="100%">

<form action="" method="GET" id="signup_form">
    
    <p>
        <label>CNIC validtion using format (12345-1234567-1) <input type="text" name="nic" autocomplete="off" autofocus tabindex="1"> 
            </label>
    </p><span> <?php echo $nicError; ?></span>
    

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">
    </p>

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider using preg_match, see more information here: https://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score -1):

```
^[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{7}-[0-9]$
```

You don't need to put 1 in the end its not needed and you also don't need - in braces

Comment: Dear my question is not that but my question is how to match that regex with the input field.

Answer (score -1):

I also faced this problem, so I searched a lot about this problem and finally I got a solution which may work:

```
form cnic input field
 

        $cnic = $_POST['cnic'];
    // patter for cnic is:
    
        $cnic_pattern = '/[0-9]{5}[-][0-9]{7}[-][0-9]{1}/';

    check weather the pattern is matched to the cnic field 
    
        if(preg_match_all[$pattern, $cnic]{
        echo "Yes! This is true";
        }else{
        echo "Oh! false;
        }
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a good thing to also include an explanation why it solves the issue (how it works), so that any future readers can learn from it.